# начинаю изучать питон, не пойму в чем ошибка?

Tags: python

```
a=[12, 23, 5]

for i in a[0]:
    print (i)
```

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: что вы пытаетесь сделать? итерироваться по первому элементу списка?

Comment: `a[0]` это число `12` в вашем случае. Вы хотите проитерироваться по числу?

Comment: Что должен делать этот код?

Comment: я понял что я делаю не так, тему можно закрывать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я сам не силён в чистом питоне, но наверное смогу помочь.
Я конкретно не понял, что вы хотите вывести. В проблеме написано, что вы хотите вытащить элементы с помощью цикла for, при этом вытащить хотите из одного числа.
Так что думаю, что нужно написать так:

```
a = [12, 23, 5]
for i in a:
     print(i)
```